# Creating streamline plot on plotly for longitude/latitude points

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly

I want to plot the ocean currents data using plotly, I have the following information:

longitude (array | shape -> (360,)): The array with longitude points 
latitude (array | shape -> (140,)): The array with latitude points 
U (2d-array | shape -> (140, 360)) : The array with x-component of current velocities 
V (2d-array | shape -> (140, 360)) : The array with y-component of current velocities

I tried it with matplot and it works well:

```
    ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.coastlines()
    mymap=plt.streamplot(lon, lat, U, V, density=6, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), color=U, cmap='autumn')
    ax.plot(xx, yy)

    plt.show()
```

But plotly throws the following error:

```
    fig = ff.create_streamline(lon, lat, U.T, V.T)
    File "C:\Users\91983\anaconda3\envs\face\lib\site-packages\plotly\figure_factory\_streamline.py", line 112, in create_streamline
    utils.validate_equal_length(x, y)
    File "C:\Users\91983\anaconda3\envs\face\lib\site-packages\plotly\figure_factory\utils.py", line 99, in validate_equal_length    raise exceptions.PlotlyError(
    _plotly_utils.exceptions.PlotlyError: Oops! Your data lists or ndarrays should be the same length.
```

I tried

```
    x, y = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
    x, y = np.vstack([x.ravel(), y.ravel()])
```

But I am unable to appropriately modify U and V

Example data:

```
lon = [-9.5, -8.5, -7.5, -6.5, -5.5]
lat = [-10.5, -11.5, -12.5]
U = [[ 0.01359653 -0.06777997 -0.01459221], [ 0.10778577 -0.0182181  -0.04552014], [-0.12153802 -0.10809003 -0.08621038], [-0.03212119  0.03420004  0.0011446 ], [0.01677546 0.02874723 0.121696  ]]
V = [[-0.0171657  -0.06966873 -0.05578572 -0.03955243 -0.05238442], [-0.01327003 -0.02819919 -0.07014654 -0.06515452 -0.00050288], [-0.01017548 -0.01393307 -0.03817951 -0.03380885  0.03111682]]
```

Comment: What shape should x, y, u and v be in order to use plotly? please post a reproducible example and the expected output

Comment: @CAPSLOCK The documentation says an evenly spaced 1D array for x and y 
and U and V should have the shape as np.meshgrid(x, y). But look like they also added a check that x and y should be the same length, which doesn't make sense to me. Link to doc -> https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.figure_factory.create_streamline.html

Comment: have you tried to take the transpose of U and V? if you look at the example you posted in your comment it looks like `U.shape = V.shape = (len(x), len(y))`

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake on my part, but it still throws the same error. I have updated the error message, it does look  like x and y is expected to have the same length.

Comment: @BananaBamboo Could you upload a reduced version of your 4 variables?

Comment: According to the reference, u and v are 2-dimensional arrays. See [here](https://plotly.com/python/streamline-plots/#basic-streamline-plot).

Comment: Added a data example for your reference @ConfusedLearner , but do note that in the actual data there is another problem, it is not 'strictly increasing' since the longitude points go from 20 degrees to 380 degrees. So I have to convert them to the range (-180 to 180) by subtracting 180 from angles > 180. 
So in practice I have a longitude array which goes from 20 to 180 then -180 to 0 then 0 to 20

Comment: Can you try this if not already checked. I tried it out and seems to work without issues. [link](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.figure_factory.create_streamline.html)

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

##### error is caused due to length(longitude) != length(latitude)

as rightly pointed out by CAPSLOCK.

Here it is code.

first line of [create_streamline](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/2e7f322c5ea4096ce6efe3b4b9a34d9647a8be9c/packages/python/plotly/plotly/figure_factory/_streamline.py#L112-L113)

```
   utils.validate_equal_length(x, y)
   utils.validate_equal_length(u, v)
```

which is comparing length of x and y, u and v.
here is [code](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/49dfcb1868e87627f032731ef2ac48e37891baf4/packages/python/plotly/plotly/figure_factory/utils.py#L97-L100)

```
length = len(args[0])
if any(len(lst) != length for lst in args):
    raise exceptions.PlotlyError(
        "Oops! Your data lists or ndarrays " "should be the same length."
    )
```

#### this means assumption of plotly in code is equal length x and y axis.

###### Your case is special case (unequal length x and y axis) for which is as of now not supported in plotly yet.

Comment: Hmm, I see. It should have been supported sadly since this is a valid use case.

Comment: I agree.
This may sound bit harsh but its harsh reality and humble suggestion.
plotly is MIT licensed . comes with no liability and warranty. 
On behalf of open source community I would request you to respect efforts of contributors. 
If you still need this feature. you can try contacting them. 
sponsor them for this. 
or
opt for paid consulting at https://plot.ly/products/consulting-and-oem/
you can as well open issue on github and add substantial bounty on https://gitpay.me/ or similar platform.

Or simply find other free and open source project which has this feature.